# using awk and bash for monitoring exec output to log

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I am looking for some help with awk and bash commands,
my project have an embedded (so very limited) hardware, 
i need to run a specific command called "digitalio show"
the command output is:

```
Input=0x50ff <-- last char only change
Output=0x7f

OR 

Input=0x50fd <-- last char only change
Output=0x7f
```

i need to extract the input parameter and convert it into either Active or Passive and log them to a file with timestamp.

the log file should look like this:

```
YYMMDDhhmmss;Active
YYMMDDhhmmss;Passive
YYMMDDhhmmss;Active
YYMMDDhhmmss;Passive
```

while logging only changes

The command "digitalio show" is an embedded specific command that give the I/O state at the time of the execution, so i basically need to log every change in the I/O into a file using a minimal tools i have in the embedded H/W.

i can run the command for every 500msec, but if i will log all the outputs i can finish the flash very quickly, so i need only log changes.

in the end this will run as a background deamon.

Thanks !

Rotem.

Comment: Whats your desired output?

Comment: $TimeStamp$;Active


$TimeStamp$;Passive

Comment: When people ask for clarification, please edit the question to clarify.  All else apart, you can format the content in the question much more than you can in a comment.  Does the output from `digitalio` include timestamps, or does the command processing the output need to add it?  What level of resolution do you need on the timestamps?  Seconds, milliseconds, microsecond, nanosecond?  Do you need the date component?  Does the output from `digitalio` get flushed as it is written, or does it get buffered?  I'd use Perl or C for this job, rather than `awk` or `bash`. Can `Input=0x57F2` appear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand, a single run of `digitalio show` command outputs two lines in the following format:

```
Input=HEX_NUMBER
Output=0x7f
```

where `HEX_NUMBER` is either `0x50ff`, or `0x50fd`. Suppose, the former stands for "Active", the latter for "Passive".

Running the command once per 500 milliseconds requires keeping the state. The most obvious implementation is a loop with a `sleep`.

However, `sleep` implementations vary. Some of them support a floating point argument (fractional seconds), and some don't. For example, the [GNU implementation](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/sleep-invocation.html#sleep-invocation) accepts *arbitrary floating point numbers*, but the [standard UNIX implementation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sleep.html) guarantees to suspend execution for *at least the integral number of seconds*. There are many alternatives, though. For instance, `usleep` from [killproc](http://ftp.suse.com/pub/projects/init/) accepts *microseconds*. Alternatively, you can write your own utility.

Let's pick the `usleep` command. Then the Bash script may look like the following:

```
#!/bin/bash -

last_state=
while true ; do
  i=$(digitalio show | awk -F= '/Input=0x[a-zA-Z0-9]+/ {print $2}')

  if test "$i" = "0x50ff" ; then
    state="Active"
  else
    state="Passive"
  fi

  if test "$state" != "$last_state" ; then
    printf '%s;%s\n' $(date '+%Y%m%d%H%M%S') "$state"
  fi

  last_state="$state"
  usleep 500000
done
```

*Sample output*

```
20161019103534;Active
20161019103555;Passive
```

The script launches `digitalio show` command in an infinite loop,  then extracts the hex part from `Input` lines with `awk`.

The `$state` variable is assigned to whether `"Active"`, or "`Passive`" depending on the value of hex string.

The `$last_state` variable keeps the value of `$state` in the last iteration. If `$state` is not equal to `$last_state`, then the state is printed to the standard output in the specific format.

Comment: if i will run this one-liner every second the log will be filled with a lot of spam, is there a way to save the last value and compare that to the next, so only changes will be written to the log ?

Comment: @RotemBar, how frequently the `digitalio show` command is supposed to be launched? Maybe you haven't written something important. Maybe it is a daemon....How the output for _single run of the command_ looks like? This is the first time you write about running the command once per second. Please clarify the question.